# How to define and assign variables in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website, but i am learning it by editing a template. So far i start to learn it quite quickly, but i cant figure everything out and i cant find everything on the internet. What i'm trying to achieve is that i can add a variable, which i place on every page of my site, so i do not have to modify it per HTML file.

This is the code (HTML):

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <h2>Interesting Topics</h2>
  <p class="news">####<a href="#####" class="more">Read More »</a> </p>
  <p class="news">####<a href="#####" class="more">Read More »</a> </p>
  <p class="news">####<a href="#####" class="more">Read More »</a> </p>
</div>
```

all #### basically need to be articles that i only have to define once, so it will show the same on every page. even better would be random/personalized articles, but that will come later i guess. if anyone can help me or has any tips, please let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language, meaning it is used to give semantics to text. Thus, you cannot declare variables, as it is not a programming language. However, what you can do instead, is use a server-side language to "feed" in the data to each page, and store the data in a separate file or something.

Comment: Yes that's what I am looking for. Do you know how i can achieve this?

Comment: There are many different server-side languages you can use to achieve this, but all of these require a server & installation. If you're using your computer to host it offline, you will need to install whichever language you choose. Personally, I think that PHP is a great choice for this; it's easy to use, especially for this purpose.

Comment: I have decided to go with php